# Why wrap Arrow function body in parentheses

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, return, arrow-functions

In a [survivejs](https://survivejs.com/react/getting-started/implementing-notes/) code example I encountered a function with a body wrapped in parentheses:

```
export default () => (
  <ul>
      {notes.map(note =>
          //some code
      )}
  </ul>
)
```

MDN explains it like this:

> ```
> // Parenthesize the body of function to return an object literal expression:
> params => ({foo: bar})
> ```

Trying to figure out what this actually means in a real world use case. Car analogies welcome (;

Comment: BTW, this particualr code works without parenthisis as well

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The MDN declaration is used to return an object literal. But I think you want to know why some people put the return instruction in parentheses regardless of the object literals.

## A Bit Theory

In JavaScript are semicolons *optional*. This can cause some errors if you dont know the behavior of the Automatic Semicolon Insertion.

When you have a `return` with a line break it will return an `undefined`

```js
const add = (x, y) => {
  return
    x + y
}

console.log( add(1, 1) )  // undefined
```

The equivalent after the Automatic Semicolon Insertion does some magic is:

```js
const add = (x, y) => {
  return;
  x + y;
};

console.log( add(1, 1) );
```

But what if the line break is a must, for example, for *readability*.. The solution is to wrap the expression into parentheses.

```js
const add = (x, y) => {
  return (
    x + y
  )
}

console.log( add(1, 1) ) // 2
```

## Your Use Case

To get rid of the parentheses we could lift up the `<ul>` tag directly after the `=>`.

```
const functionName = xs => <ul>
    {xs.map(note =>
        //some code
    )}
</ul>
```

But now it is not really readable anymore.. so we should reinsert the parentheses quickly

```
const functionName = xs => (
    <ul>
        {xs.map( x =>
            //some code
        )}
    </ul>
)
```

Answer (score 6):

Without parenthesis, the object declaration brackets `{}` are considered as the arrow function body which will lead a logic error.

This `params => { foo: 'bar'}` is considered as

```
params => { 
             foo: 'bar'
          }
```

```js
const func1 = params => { foo: 'bar'};
console.log(func1());

const func2 = params => ({ foo: 'bar'});
console.log(func2());
```

Comment: Ok, got it in the use case which you presented, any idea why it belongs in the code above? (maybe a mistake)

Comment: @Skarlinski Usually, it should work fine as its JSX, but if you are using any linting, that might raise warnings. Also, another reason for parenthesis could be that JSX can be of multiple line and so to wrap in 1 statement, it might be necessary

Comment: I shared a code example from a book in the question, he consistently uses this format throughout, and I am trying to see if there is an actual benefit

Comment: @Rajesh that helps. But out of off topic: isn't jsx always transpiled to a single statement?

Comment: @rajesh and furthermore, is this a best practice for jsx which I should adopt?

Comment: *isn't jsx always transpiled to a single statement*, No. So if you have nested components, it would be multiple statements. *is this a best practice*, kindof. Practices are usually more specific to projects but as a common practice, its more advisable using them to wrap your JSX. If you have a complex JSX, it can become difficult to read.

Comment: @Skarlinski You can refer following [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/c82cae8t/8/). As you can see, you do not need parenthesis but its using JSX and not TSX, and no lint. You will also see, `MyComplexComponent` is very primitive but is still a bit difficult to read. Dividing into smaller controller would help. Now imagine, if this JSX grew to say 100 lines. You will get lost. Parenthesis would help you in organizing JSX btu is not required necessarily.

Comment: @Rajesh, I don't see it yet, but it will prbbly hit me a bit later. Thanks!